# Jenkins : Default content is not displayed in email body when attachment also added along with Default Contains in email body

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins , I want to send email after a jenkins slave job is finished with hyperlinked title as "Please see-> DETAILED REPORT <- for more information... " and test results (testngReport.html  ) as the email body.

Here is my Configuration of "Editable E-mail notification"  :

```
    Default Content :

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
<b>Please see<b/>
        <a href="Path to html report " >-> DETAILED REPORT <-for more information... </a>
        <br />
        <br />




    pre-sent Script :

    def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("target/surefire-reports/Suite/Report.html")
               msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");
```

Please refer screenshot for details configuration

[image]

Tried with so many ways but,every time the email I received is missing this content/text (hyperlink ).

But When I tried only for "Default content" (by removing the code from "Pre-sent Script" field  `def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("target/surefire-reports/Suite/Report.html")msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");)`
Same Hyperlink is displayed on email Body.

Stuck from Last 3 days. Please let me know where am making mistake.

Actually I want email as per below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jenkins masters , Kindly guide me to make it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Got the solution , It was my mistake. I was trying to add Path in Project level. It need to add at Global Configuration. Secondly no need to add anything in   pre-sent Script :